# Django how to include all columns from one table, but a only subset of columns in a different table, using tbl.only?

Tags: django, django-3.0, django-4.0

I want to join a child table to the parent table, and return all columns from the child table (child.*), but only specific columns from a parent table (parent.foo, parent.bar), using `only` but not `defer`.

Is there any syntax to issue a SQL similar to the following:

```
select child.*, 
    parent.foo, parent.bar
from child join parent on child.parent_id = parent.id
```

I do not want to use `defer`, because the `parent` table has even more columns than the `child` table.

I currently have to spell out every column that I want using `only`:

```
Child.objects.select_related('parent').only(
    'id', 'name', 'creation_date', 
    'parent__foo', 'parent__bar'
).all()
```

But I would like to include all the columns from Child.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
Child.object.select_related('parent').only(*[f.get_attname() for f in Child._meta.fields], 'parent__foo', 'parent__bar').all()
```